# REVERSE - DISM /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_2018.702.514.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Tags: powershell, calculator, dism

I'm New to the Sys Admin world and ran a script at work to remove some bloatware form new windows 10 machines.
In my Excitement, I removed too much and am looking for a way to get windows calculator back. Its worth noting the windows store is also removed as intended.

This is the line we ran on the machine to remove the calculator at first.
DISM /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_2018.702.514.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe

I've tried a few options to re-instate the Calculator but can't get anything to work. 
Please Help, Ty!

Comment: have you tried: Get-AppxPackage -allusers *windowscalculator* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}

Comment: This is the error message:
Get-AppxPackage : The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x800706FD)
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AppxPackage -allusers windowscalculator | Foreach {Add-AppxPackag ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AppxPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Comman
   ds.GetAppxPackageCommand